# Makefile: get prerequisites of target prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there any native makefile (GNU make, etc.) way to get prerequisites of target prerequisites? These question is ***not*** about dependency check from source files by compiler (g++ -MM, for example).

Can't find anything on subject. And as I can see, there is no special variables for this case.

To illustrate problem, here is my definition of compilation recipe from C++ source to object, pretty standard though:

```
##### UNIVERSAL COMPILE #####
%.o: %.cpp %.hpp
   ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@
```

And then I need to build really big chains of dependencies:

```
a: a.o
b: b.o a.o
c: c.o b.o a.o
d: d.o c.o b.o a.o
etc, up to N times...
```

It is necessary because of this linking recipe:

```
##### UNIVERSAL LINK #####
%: %.o
   ${LN} ${LNFLAGS} $^ -o $@
```

As you can see, recipe takes ***all of supplied dependencies***, but need to get ***all dependencies of all supplied dependencies***.

There is no problem with overall program linking, as it is in recipe:

```
##### PROGRAM LINK ######
${BIN}: ${OBJ}
   ${LN} ${LNFLAGS} ${OBJ} -o ${BINDIR}/$@
```

But I need to do unit-testing, and units depends one on each others dependencies and hierarchy of testing for subsystems is very tiring to write as dependency chains that hard-coded.

Maybe I'm doing it in wrong way? Maybe there is alternatives to this link recipe? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "... of target prerequisites"? I get what "prerequisites of target" means but not "get prerequisites of target prerequisites".

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it in the wrong way.  Why would you want to declare that `b.o` must be recompiled every time `a.o` changes (that's (one of) the things it means when you specify a prerequisite pf `b.o : a.o`)?  That's not what needs to happen and it doesn't make sense.

You need to list *all* the object files as prerequisites of the single executable file, for example:

```
exe: a.o b.o c.o d.o ...
```

That's it.

Comment: Excuse me, I wrote not that was meant to be, changed question and, specifically, dependency chain that reflect linking recipe.

Comment: I think what he may be asking is something that I've wished make could do for a little bit now which is to support a way of getting the pre-requisites of the pre-requisites in the body of a target (some other automatic variable or whatever). I've needed this for creating tarballs of "source" files and build/munged results files together on occasion.

Comment: @EtanReisner But he didn't list `b.o: b.o a.o`; he said `b: b.o a.o`. That's different, right?